# Redirection with udp Android ports

Tags: java, android, sockets, udp, port

I have 1 application running on two separate emulators and I need them to communicate.
Each emulator needs to send or receive information.

Using the classes below for example, for the applications I would have:

Emulator #1) Server-5554
receiving port=9502, sending port=9503.

Emulator #2) Client-5556
receiving port=9504, sending port=9505

then I would do the following commands in cmd:

```
telnet localhost 5554

redir add udp:9503:9504

quit

telnet localhost 5556

redir add udp:9505:9502

quit
```

using `add <protocol>:<host-port>:<guest-port>` from the docs
from http://developer.android.com/tools/devices/emulator.html#redirection

This does not work however. One thing I don't understand is that you need a port to send and receive, but the docs only provide host:guest, but i assume host is the port its sending to be redirected with guest port its receiving from. I'm really not understanding this, examples would be very helpful.

For receiving packets:

```
public class ChatReceiverAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Void, String, String> {
    Context context;

    ChatReceiverAsyncTask(Context context) {
        this.context = context;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Void... params) {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[50];
        DatagramSocket socket;
        DatagramPacket packet;
        String decoded = null;
        try {
            packet = new DatagramPacket(buffer, buffer.length);
            socket = new DatagramSocket(9502);
            socket.setReuseAddress(true);
            while (true) {
                socket.receive(packet);
                decoded = new String(packet.getData(), "UTF-8");
                System.out.println("Client recieved " + decoded);
                publishProgress(decoded);
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return decoded;
    }
```

For sending packets:

```
@Override
public void onCreate() {
    try {
        socket = new DatagramSocket(null);
        socket = new DatagramSocket(9503);
        socket.setReuseAddress(true);
    } catch (SocketException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void sendMessage(Message message, InetAddress destinationHost,
        int port) {
    try {
        byte[] sendData = (message.sender + ": " + message.message)
                .getBytes("UTF-8");
        DatagramPacket sendPacket = new DatagramPacket(sendData,
                sendData.length, destinationHost, port);
        socket.send(sendPacket);
        Log.d("sendMessage", "sent packet");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```